# Does Unity5 features valid on android low versions such as android 2.3?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

We are trying to develop app based on Unity5 features. And I want to know does unity5 new features run ok on android low versions such as android 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements

> FOR RUNNING UNITY GAMES
>
> ...
>
> Android: OS 2.3.1 or later; ARMv7 (Cortex) CPU or Atom CPU; OpenGL ES 2.0 or later.

On older devices, which will have slower CPUs/GPUs than their newer counterparts, performance may be an issue.